# How to change the typeface in an image button?

Tags: android

I am new user in android. I am trying to change the font size of the image button. But my java file shows error. Can anybody tell me how to show text in image button and also to change typeface in an image button. My coding in java file is as follows.

```
public class AyurvedaMenuActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ImageButton btnAyurveda, btnDiseases, btnHerbs, btnProducts, btnHospitals, btnResearchCenters, btnDoctors, btnInstitutes, btnContactUs;
TextView tvMainTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ayurveda_menu);


    btnAyurveda = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bAMAyurveda);
    btnContactUs = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bAMContactUs);
    btnDiseases = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bAMDiseases);
    btnDoctors = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bAMDoctors);
    btnHerbs = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bAMHerbs);
    btnHospitals = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bAMHospitals);
    btnInstitutes = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bAMInstitutes);
    btnProducts = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bAMProducts);
    btnResearchCenters = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bAMResearchCenters);
    tvMainTitle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMainTitle);
    String fontpath =  "fonts/magneto_bold.ttf";
/*String fontpath =  "fonts/forte.ttf";*/
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),fontpath);
    btnAyurveda.setTypeface(tf);
    tvMainTitle.setTypeface(tf);
    btnAyurveda.setTypeface(tf);
    btnDiseases.setTypeface(tf);
    btnContactUs.setTypeface(tf);
    btnDoctors.setTypeface(tf);
    btnHerbs.setTypeface(tf);
    btnHospitals.setTypeface(tf);
    btnInstitutes.setTypeface(tf);
    btnResearchCenters.setTypeface(tf);
    btnContactUs.setTypeface(tf);
    btnProducts.setTypeface(tf);
    btnAyurveda.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnContactUs.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDiseases.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDoctors.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnHerbs.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnHospitals.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnInstitutes.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnProducts.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnResearchCenters.setOnClickListener(this);

    //databaseEntry();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ayurveda_menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("V id"+v.getId());
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bAMAyurveda:
        startActivity(new Intent(AyurvedaMenuActivity.this,AyurvedaActivity.class).putExtra("AyurdevaActivity", 1));

        break;

    case R.id.bAMContactUs:
        startActivity(new Intent(AyurvedaMenuActivity.this,ContactUsActivity.class).putExtra("ContactUsActivity", 9));
        break;

    case R.id.bAMDiseases:
        startActivity(new Intent(AyurvedaMenuActivity.this,MenuListActivity.class).putExtra("MenuListActivity", 2));
        break;

    case R.id.bAMDoctors:
        startActivity(new Intent(AyurvedaMenuActivity.this,MenuListActivity.class).putExtra("MenuListActivity", 7));
        break;

    case R.id.bAMHerbs:
        startActivity(new Intent(AyurvedaMenuActivity.this,MenuListActivity.class).putExtra("MenuListActivity", 3));
        break;

    case R.id.bAMHospitals:
        startActivity(new Intent(AyurvedaMenuActivity.this,MenuListActivity.class).putExtra("MenuListActivity", 5));
        break;

    case R.id.bAMInstitutes:
        startActivity(new Intent(AyurvedaMenuActivity.this,MenuListActivity.class).putExtra("MenuListActivity", 8));
        break;

    case R.id.bAMProducts:
        startActivity(new Intent(AyurvedaMenuActivity.this,MenuListActivity.class).putExtra("MenuListActivity", 4));
        break;

    case R.id.bAMResearchCenters:
        startActivity(new Intent(AyurvedaMenuActivity.this,MenuListActivity.class).putExtra("MenuListActivity", 6));
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

and my xml file is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/b_image"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".AyurvedaMenuActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMainTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title_image"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/ayurveda_title"
    android:textColor="#3D0303"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="385dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.27" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bAMAyurveda"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_image"
            android:textColor="#3D0303"
            android:text="@string/ayurveda" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bAMDiseases"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#3D0303"
            android:background="@drawable/button_image"
            android:text="@string/disease" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bAMHerbs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#3D0303"
            android:background="@drawable/button_image"
            android:text="@string/herbs" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bAMProducts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#3D0303"
            android:background="@drawable/button_image"
            android:text="@string/products" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bAMHospitals"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_image"
            android:textColor="#3D0303"
            android:text="@string/hospitals" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bAMResearchCenters"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#3D0303"
            android:background="@drawable/button_image"
            android:text="@string/research_centers" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bAMDoctors"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#3D0303"
            android:background="@drawable/button_image"
            android:text="@string/doctors" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bAMInstitutes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#3D0303"
            android:background="@drawable/button_image"
            android:text="@string/institutes" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bAMContactUs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#3D0303"
            android:background="@drawable/button_image"
            android:text="@string/contact_us" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/title_image"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why are you putting the whole code...?? this may tedious to viewer.. post only pies of code

Comment: Just use 1 button can illustrate the issue.

Comment: What is the error? That is most important right now

Comment: OP doesn't know how to set the typeface in image button?

Comment: I am really sorry guys. I was confused as to how much code should I add.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

you can't use `android:text` in `ImageButton`

I recommend you to use a **normal button**  like below

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/buttonok" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_image"
    android:text="@string/ayurveda"/>
```

You can put the drawable wherever you want

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/button_image"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_image"
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/button_image"
```

then you can add your `Typeface` like below

```
 Button btnAyurveda = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAMAyurveda);
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),fontpath);
 btnAyurveda.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
Button n=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helv Neue 67 Med Cond.ttf");
n.setText("show");
n.setTypeface(typeface);
```